# cakephp 500 for first page

Tags: cakephp

I had just moved my local copy of cakephp project, onto the shared server hosting. The problem I encountered is a 500 internal server error for the home page of the website.

The home page itself has no problem loading up content and description, but somehow, it is not using the template in the default.ctp due to the HTTP 500 error.

The controller for that home page is: /articles/home

And other methods in that same controller [eg: /articles/about], works as normal.

Routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'home
```

Comment: Did you delete the tmp files, look/show the relevant error from the error log. `The home page itself has no problem loading up content and description` <- not clear what that means, since you say it's a 500

Comment: oh gah, its a dumb error. an extra slash when listing a path. thanks for the tip !

Comment: please answer your own question (and then accept the answer) or delete the question if you don't think it will help anyone else.